# How to avoid evaluation of all of 'iif' expression?

Tags: .net, vb.net, casting, lazy-evaluation, iif

Is VB.NET 2005, is there a way to do the following without it throwing an `invalid cast exception` on the attempt to cast the empty string to an integer?

```
Dim strInput As String = String.Empty
Dim intResult As Integer = IIf(IsNumeric(strInput), CInt(strInput), 100)
```

Comment: I would say your `IsNumeric` method should be returning false for empty strings. But why are you checking `strInput` then using `str`?

Comment: You can't - `IIf` is not an expression, but a function, so it has to first evaluate all arguments before execution.

Comment: @JoelEtherton: sorry, just a typo. It does return false but it is throwing an exception I think because it tries to evaluate the whole expression anyway.

Answer (score 9):

VB.NET has a real ternary operator now (after 2008)

```
Dim intResult = If(IsNumeric(strInput), CInt(strInput), 100)
```

This differs from the IIF because it uses the short-circuiting evaluation.
If the test expression evaluates to true, the FalsePart is just ignored or viceversa

As Mr Marek Kembrowsky says in its comment, the IIF is a function and its parameters are all evaluated before being passed in while the IF (as a ternary operator) is an added functionality of the VB compiler.

However I don't like to use the shortcuts provided by the Microsoft.VisualBasic compatibility namespace when I program in VB.NET. The Framework provides better solutions like the TryParse set of methods. Your example will fail if the input string exceeds the Integer.MaxValue.

A better approach could be

```
Dim d As decimal
if Not Decimal.TryParse(strInput, d)  then d = 100
```

or, if you have a floating point `string` (? ok ok, you have understand what I mean)

```
Dim d As Double
if Not Double.TryParse(strInput, d)  then d = 100
```

Comment: What are your main objections to using the VisualBasic namespace?

Comment: Mainly a personal preference, I wish to cut all ties with VB6, then the hassle to distribute Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll (in reality I have not checked from the 1.1 times, perhaps there is no need to distribute it)

Answer (score 1):

The *If* solution will work ... but IsNumeric() isnt the correct check. What if strInput is a number but exceeds integer.maxvalue? Better work with TryParse instead.

```
Dim i As Integer
If Not Integer.TryParse("1234567890", i) Then i = 100
```

or

```
Dim j As Integer = If(Integer.TryParse("123456789", Nothing), Integer.Parse("123456789"), 100)
```

Comment: +1 Good point, but the second example should be avoided (in my opinion)

Comment: CJ7: Integer IS the right type (for an integer). In my sample I only replacred StrInput by "1234567890".
@Steve: The OP's original code was a one-line, so maybe he prefers this style.

Comment: It is not for the one-line style, it is because you force a double evaluation of the input string (if true).

Comment: What I mean is that if it is envisaged that the input might exceed `Integer.MaxValue` then the programmer should be using `Long` instead of `Integer` to begin with.

Comment: The problem is not what the programmer wants the input to be, but what the user gives him. Hell! Programming could be so much fun if there weren't these damned users ... ;) By using Isnumeric() you already admit, that the input string might be everything (like "apple", "foo"). If it can be "Foo" it can also be something that is Numeric, but does not fit into an Int or even Long. And we usually dont want to use BigInteger everywhere, do we?

Comment: Yes, damned users, I stand them just because sometimes I get paid :0)

Answer (score 0):

One way round the issue is:

```
Dim strInput As String = String.Empty
Dim intResult As Integer = IIf(IsNumeric(strInput), strInput, 100)
```

This way the casting is done implicitly and there is no chance of any invalid cast exceptions.

Comment: @igrimpe: a string that has already passed the `IsNumeric` test

Comment: Test this: "123456789123456789". Does it pass IsNumeric?